# Iterating over flat array and building json in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a flat array of files that's dynamically built from a directory structure, a sample of such output can be seen here;

```
Array (
    [0] => filename-in-root.png
    [1] => another-filename-in-root.png
    [directory.subdirectory.0] => logo-of-some-sort.jpeg
    [directory.subdirectory.1] => image-of-queen.jpg
    [anotherdirectory.0] => a-screenshot-png
    [anotherdir.0] => a-lovely-picture.png
    [nextdirectory.0] => me-giving-the-bird.png
)
```

Then what im doing is feeding this output into another function to produce json output i can plug into my javascript component.

It works great for files in the root, and also if there is only 1 file in a directory / subdirectory ... BUT when adding multiple files to directories and subdirectories, it causes the directory structure to be output again as seen below;

```
[
    [0,"/","/",false,1],
    [1,"/filename-in-root.png","filename-in-root.png",true,1],
    [2,"/another-filename-in-root.png","another-filename-in-root.png",true,1],
    [3,"/directory","Directory",false,1],
    [4,"/directory/subdirectory","Subdirectory",false,2],
    [5,"/directory/subdirectory/logo-of-some-sort.jpeg","logo-of-some-sort.jpeg",true,3],
    [6,"/directory","Directory",false,1],
    [7,"/directory/subdirectory","Subdirectory",false,2],
    [8,"/directory/subdirectory/image-of-queen.jpg","image-of-queen.jpg",true,3],
    and so on.........
]
```

As you can see, item 6 and 7 shouldnt be there as item 8 is already marked in the right directory, the number at the end indicates how many indents it should have.

The code im using to generate this is as follows;

```
function generateJson($flatArray)
{
    $arrayId = 1;
    $final_array = [[0, '/', '/', false, 1]];
    ksort($flatArray, SORT_STRING);

    foreach ($flatArray as $key => $val) {
        $exploded_key = explode('.', $key);
        foreach ($exploded_key as $k => $v) {
            if ($k == sizeof($exploded_key)-1) {
                $count = 1;
                for ($i = 0; $i < count(array_slice($exploded_key, 0, $k)); $i++) {
                    $count++;
                }
                $final_array[] = [$arrayId, '/' . join('/', array_slice($exploded_key, 0, $k)) . '/' . $val, $val, true, $count];
                $arrayId++;
            } else {
                $count = 1;
                for ($i = 0; $i < count(array_slice($exploded_key, 0, $k)); $i++) {
                    $count++;
                }
                $final_array[] = [$arrayId, '/' . join('/', array_slice($exploded_key, 0, $k + 1)), ucfirst($v), false, $count];
                $arrayId++;
            }
        }
    }

    return json_encode($final_array);
}
```

Im so stuck on this ... any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before appending any element to the `$final_array` (which is `json_encode`d), we can check if it already exists to avoid duplication.

Also we can decrease the duplication in the code:

```
function generateJson($flatArray)
{
    $arrayId = 1;
    $final_array = [[0, '/', '/', false, 1]];
    $final_paths = []; // New array to store paths
    ksort($flatArray, SORT_STRING);
    foreach ($flatArray as $key => $val) {
        $exploded_key = explode('.', $key);
        foreach ($exploded_key as $k => $v) {
            $count = 1;
            // Changes start from here (in addition to initializing $final_paths array above)
            $end = count(array_slice($exploded_key, 0, $k));
            for ($i = 0; $i < $end; $i++) {
                $count++;
            }
            // The only statement changed is wrapped with the if-statement
            if ($k == sizeof($exploded_key)-1) {
                $new_element = [$arrayId, '/' . join('/', array_slice($exploded_key, 0, $k)) . '/' . $val, $val, true, $count];
            } else {
                $new_element = [$arrayId, '/' . join('/', array_slice($exploded_key, 0, $k + 1)), ucfirst($v), false, $count];
            }
            // *This is it*: append the element ONLY IF it is not in the array
            if(!in_array($new_element[1], $final_paths)) {
                $final_paths[] = $new_element[1];
                $final_array[] = $new_element;
                $arrayId++;
            }
        }
    }
    return json_encode($final_array);
}
```

Maybe not the best solution (from running-time perspective), but it should work.

Comment: That gave the same output as the original function

Comment: and what about files that are in the first direcory and then others that are in a subdirectory of that, wont that kill the folder names

Comment: Ahhh it wont find the value because of the $arrayId changes, so although the string will be the same, the first value in the json field will always be different ... Is there any way we can tell it to ignore that number and just focus on the rest?

Comment: I tested the updated code, & it is not duplicating paths

Comment: YES!!!!!!!! That worked a treat .. Thank you so so much, you have saved me pulling out the rest of the hair on my head .... I really appreciate that!!